# Máximo y mínimo en un vector C++ con números de un archivo

Tags: c++, array, archivo

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en C++ que mande 100 números aleatorio a un archivo, después los recoja y obtenga el número mayor y el número menor. He intentado hacerlo introduciendo los cien números en un vector y sacando el máximo y el mínimo. El archivo lo crea bien y manda los números correctamente, pero a la hora de recogerlos genera números muy extraños. He intentado pasar la parte en la que el vector lo ordena al main, pero eso me ha generado más problemas aun, por eso decidí dejarlo ahí.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void escritura();
void lectura();

int main()
{
    escritura();
    lectura();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void escritura()
{
    int num, c;
    ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open("numeros.txt", ios::out);

    if (archivo.fail()) {
        cout << "No se puede abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (c = 0; c <= 99; c++) {
        num = 0 + rand() % (201 - 1);
        archivo << num << endl;
    }
    archivo.close();
}

void lectura()
{
    int i = 0, numero[100];
    ifstream archivo;

    archivo.open("numeros.txt", ios::in);

    if (archivo.fail()) {
        cout << "No se puede abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;
    archivo >> numero[i];
    while (!archivo.eof()) { //Mientras no sea el final del archivo
        {
            i++;
            archivo >> numero[i];
        }
        archivo.close();

        int mayor, menor;
        mayor = numero[0]; //Le asignamos el primer elemento del array
        menor = numero[0]; //Así empezamos a comparar

        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (numero[i] > mayor) {
                mayor = numero[i];
            }
            if (numero[i] < menor) {
                menor = numero[i];
            }
        }
        printf("El mayor es %d\n", mayor);
        printf("El menor es %d\n", menor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No has inicializado la formación `int numero[100];` por lo que tendrá valores residuales de memoria, si añades unas llaves vacías a la formación, todos sus elementos se inicializarán a cero:

```
int numero[100]{}; // Cien elementos a cero.
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en  cuenta.

- Las cabeceras `<stdlib.h>` y `<time.h>` son cabeceras del lenguaje C; si realmente necesitas usarlas (que no es el caso) deberías usar la versión adaptada a C++ que es `<cstdlib>` y `<ctime>` respectivamente. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más del tema.
- La herramienta de generación de números aleatorios `rand` está considerada como ineficiente e insegura, hasta el punto que se valora deprecarla. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183221/2742) para saber más del tema.

  - Por otro lado, dicha herramienta genera [números distribuidos uniformemente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_uniforme_discreta) en el rango de cero a [`RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX) si haces módulo (`%`) sobre un valor que no sea divisor de `RAND_MAX`, falsearás la distribución. Usa la cabecera C++ `<random>` para generar números pseudoaleatorios adecuadamente.
- No abuses de la cláusula `using namespace std;` si realmente quieres usarla, hazlo en el ámbito más pequeño posible.
- Los flujos de salida de datos a archivo (`std::ofstream`) ya son de salida, no necesitas especificar al abrirlos que pretendes sacar datos (`ios::out`).
- Los flujos de entrada de datos a archivo (`std::ifstream`) ya son de entrada, no necesitas especificar al abrirlos que pretendes leer datos (`ios::in`).
- No debes comprobar en el bucle `while` si has alcanzado el final del archivo ya que leerás un dato de más. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/320974/2742) para saber más del tema.
- Favorece el preincremento frente al postincremento. Lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber más del tema.
- En C++ la salida por consola se hace mediante `std::cout`, la función `printf` es de C.

#### Propuesta.

Con los consejos anteriores, tu código [podría parecerse a](https://tio.run/##pVPbbsIwDH1uvsLrJNZqF4H2MAGle9rrfmAgVFKzWWoTlKZoE@q3M5c0BSbtIu0pjn3ic3zcys3m9lXK/f6SlCzqHCEhXVmDWZmKY85kKtdnmbUHia2mHLCShmxtsigWOxHQGqLK5pOJ7nCQGflGW70LVV2i0dWdfbdhE4uA0cEB6jiWOW5JIrhj6oulHY3H9w/wigpNlmsTOUAUxz2mVrTWplySssucmJdWtSWtkhT8VfI1Gt7AeMzP@B3jIWI8EMxgOOXjYgajIUfX18TigqDTDUly3qQXErelq7m6Yh2NCLCo0AuSurZtNXzWUCFsamTnspUhA1h4R@7mKpyKpvOxQHniIgtzdr2wpsWuaTX31tKfrP06oZ9nMPhh2DT1vLT411huhjL7YBUz33O4uIES1Xmqxf62jXYe38udyVEnPJ7EE1dvPw3P5M70@wdt/TCs@DLmU9GxYQVhm@m43dqZwoMODB7UXfuPg/s6L0i57Z78MkzbL55jgxwqdkA0@/0n):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>

void escritura()
{
    /* Los flujos de datos con implícitamente convertibles a booleano,
    si el flujo no se puede abrir, la expresión será 'false'. */
    if (std::ofstream archivo{"numeros.txt"})
    {
        std::random_device device;
        std::mt19937 generador(device());
        /* Generador de números aleatorios distribuidos
        uniformemente entre 0 y 99. */
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(0, 99);

        for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
            archivo << distribucion(generador) << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No se puede abrir el archivo.\n";
}

void lectura()
{
    // Inicializamos todos los números de la formación a cero.
    int numero[100]{};

    if (std::ifstream archivo{"numeros.txt"})
    {
        for (int i = 0; archivo && i != 100; ++i)
            archivo >> numero[i];
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No se puede abrir el archivo.\n";

    int mayor = numero[0], menor = numero[0];

    for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    {
        mayor = mayor < numero[i] ? numero[i] : mayor;
        menor = menor > numero[i] ? numero[i] : menor;
    }

    std::cout << "El mayor es " << mayor << '\n'
        << "El menor es " <<  menor << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    escritura();
    lectura();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas ubicando mal `archivo.close();` en la función `lectura`, está dentro del bloque `while`, esto hace que no termine de leer completamente el archivo ya que se estaría cerrando apenas leído el segundo elemento, entonces `archivo.close();` debería estar fuera de este bloque, además, el bloque `while` debería terminar antes de las declaraciones `int mayor, menor;`, incluso, si te das cuenta el bloque `for` está anidado dentro del `while` y no debería estar así, la función `lectura` corregida sería:

```
void lectura() {
    int i = 0, numero[100];
    ifstream archivo;

    archivo.open("numeros.txt", ios::in);

    if (archivo.fail()) {
        cout << "No se puede abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;
    archivo >> numero[i];
    while (!archivo.eof()) //Mientras no sea el final del archivo
    {
        i++;
        archivo >> numero[i];
    }//aquí termina el bloque while
    archivo.close();

    int mayor, menor;
    mayor = numero[0]; //Le asignamos el primer elemento del array
    menor = numero[0]; //Así empezamos a comparar

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (numero[i] > mayor) {
            mayor = numero[i];
        }
        if (numero[i] < menor) {
            menor = numero[i];
        }
    }
    printf("El mayor es %d\n", mayor);
    printf("El menor es %d\n", menor);
}
```

Bueno, no soy un experto en eso de las buenas prácticas de programación pero creo deberías evitar mezclar cabeceras de C y C++, en este caso puedes obviar `#include <stdlib.h>` y cambiar `time.h` por `ctime`, puedes encontrar más detalles [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c).

Comment: No, el problema no es el que describes si no que no ha inicializado la formación.

Comment: Así como está compiló y funcionó, he usado Visual C++ 2017

Comment: El compilador que usaste no tiene nada que ver con que el problema sea diferente al que mencionas.

Comment: Pues el hecho de que `archivo.close();` debía estar fuera del bloque `while` así como el bloque `for` en la función `lectura`, creo que no me equivoque con eso,  ¿o a que te refieres?.

Comment: Me refiero a que no inicializó la formación, por lo tanto la formación obtuvo valores residuales de memoria. Ese es el origen de los "*números muy extraños*" que menciona Edurex. El cerrar el archivo en el bucle no provoca la aparición de esos números, provoca que no se lea el archivo al completo.

Comment: a!, claro, tienes razón, no es que se hayan leído esos valores sino que la formación no se inicializó en su totalidad, justamente por eso era necesario corregir el bloque `while`, para terminar de leer el archivo y terminar la inicialización de la formación.