# srand no me funciona

Tags: c++, random

Me salió un error que no entiendo:

```
[Error] expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token".
[Error] conversión esperada de constructor, destructor o tipo antes del token '('.
```

Lo que quería hacer es un programa que te pida las filas y columnas de una matriz después que le de un valores random a la matriz después que muestre la matriz que encuentre el numero de mayor valor de la matriz y que al final muestre ese numero.

El código se los demuestro abajo.

1. librerías, prototipos, declaración de enteros y matriz

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;
srand(time(NULL));

void pedir();
void generar();
void imprimir();
int comprobar();

int matriz[100][100];
int filas, columnas;
```

2. funcion int main()

```
int main(){
    
    pedir();
    generar();
    imprimir();
    cout<<"el mayor numero de la matriz es: "<<comprobar();
    cout<<endl;
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

3)funciones

```
void pedir(){
    cout<<"introducir el numero de filas"<<endl;
    cin>>filas;
    cout<<"introducir el numero de columnas"<<endl;
    cin>>columnas;
}

void generar(){
    for(int f=0;f<filas;f++){
        for(int c=0;c<columnas;c++){
            matriz[f][c]=1+rand()%(101-1);
        }
    }
}

void imprimir(){
    cout<<endl;
    for(int f=0;f<filas;f++){
        for(int c=0;c<columnas;c++){
            cout<<" ["<<matriz[f][c]<<"] ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int comprobar(){
    int mayor=0;
    cout<<endl;
    
    for(int f=0;f<filas;f++){
        for(int c=0;c<columnas;c++){
            if(matriz[f][c]>mayor){
                mayor=matriz[f][c];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return mayor;
}
```

El programa no se puede abrir se los mando completo para que me ayuden con los errores y para leer sus sugerencias para mejorar el código.
gracias.

Comment: Para la siguiente, por favor, **remarca de alguna forma la línea que te provoca el error**.

Answer (score 4):

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Eso es **una llamada** a una función.

Sin embargo, las llamadas a funciones **no se pueden colocar en cualquier sitio**: solo se pueden hacer desde el cuerpo de una función o desde sentencias de asignación (`X = srand( time( NULL ) );`)

Si te preguntas porqué si se pueden hacer desde la lista de argumentos, es porque esto es equivalente a una asignación. Puedes verlo como:

```
auto tmp = time( NULL );
X = srand( tmp );
```

Así pues, simplemente, mueve esa llamada algún sitio en el que sea legal; por ejemplo, al cuerpo de tu función `main( )`.

```
  int main( ) {
    srand( time( NULL ) ); // <-- AQUÍ
    pedir( );
    generar( );
  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Tu código, a parte del error mencionado por [Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/377110/2742), tiene errores de algoritmo y hace uso de malas prácticas.

1. Estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pero haces uso de cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c).

   Las cabeceras `<stdlib.h>` y `<time.h>` no deben ser usadas en programas de C++, si realmente necesitas algo de ellas (que no es el caso) deberías usar las versiones adaptadas a C++ que son `<cstdlib>` y `<ctime>`. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más del tema.
2. Evita usar variables globales.

   Las variables globales son muy problemáticas y propensas a errores, evita usarlas. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183489/2742) para saber más del tema.
3. La función `rand` pertenece a las rutinas de C.

   Se considera una función lenta, ineficiente e insegura, tanto es así que se valora deprecar su uso en C++, no la uses. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183044/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-rand-y-srand/183221#183221) para saber más del tema.

---

Mi propuesta es que uses el motor de números pseudo-aleatorios de C++ y que por supuesto, sigas las recomendaciones anteriores, si lo haces tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

using Doblete = std::pair<int, int>;
using Fila = std::vector<int>;
using Matriz = std::vector<Fila>;
```

Usaremos `<vector>` para crear la matriz dinámicamente, haciendo que el tamaño sea verdaderamente arbitrario en lugar de limitarlo a un máximo de cien. La cabecera `<utility>` nos da acceso al tipo `std::pair`, la `<algorithm>` a las funciones `std::max` y `std::max_element` y `<limits>` a la plantilla `std::numeric_limits`. Los alias `Doblete`, `Fila` y `Matriz` hacen que el código sea más fácil de comprender.

```
Doblete pedir()
{
    Doblete resultado;

    std::cout << "introducir el numero de filas\n";
    std::cin >> resultado.first;

    std::cout << "introducir el numero de columnas\n";
    std::cin >> resultado.second;

    return resultado;
}
```

Pedimos los datos dentro de la función `pedir` y los devolvemos como `Doblete`, nos ahorramos así una variable global.

```
Matriz generar(const Doblete &tamanyo)
{
    Matriz resultado(tamanyo.first, Fila(tamanyo.second, 0));

    std::random_device dispositivo;
    std::mt19937 generador(dispositivo());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(1, 100);

    for (auto &fila : resultado)
    {
        for (auto &valor : fila)
        {
            valor = distribucion(generador);
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Generamos la matriz dentro de la función `generar`; no nos debe preocupar la copia del resultado desde dentro de la función a fuera de la función pues el estándar de C++ garantiza que ese copia será obviada (*copy elysion optimization*). Se usa el motor de números pseudo-aleatorios de C++.

El resto del código quedaría así:

```
void imprimir(const Matriz &matriz)
{
    for (const auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
        {
            std::cout << " [" << valor << "] ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int comprobar(const Matriz &matriz)
{
    int resultado = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

    for (const auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        resultado = std::max(resultado, *std::max_element(fila.begin(), fila.end()));
    }

    return resultado;
}

int main()
{
    const auto &matriz = generar(pedir());
    imprimir(matriz);

    std::cout << "El mayor numero de la matriz es: " << comprobar(matriz) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTbjtMwEH2uv8IqUjdFoWrVB7RtNk/AG1/AosqN3TKSL5HtVBS0317GTpwLCwWpapTxmeNz5pKqrt9Vkunz7fYGdCUbLmgBxnkrmCrJELNMczOJXETljR1HGg8S/HUcYvJsLPhvk0wJCrwrCWkc6DP9YI5SeEGfqPN8t6sZ2AK0zyn@lfsO9AkkS4j25mJ8/Jl5Cz9@A4QcRJB0QS042GxJfpJZClnhGukZNwibxdzKNJ4WBZ0jvTW8qcBSIalulLCGovwTsrpnPd@nBNC0LAem1Qms8//PVxnZKH2f0onKaB44rfCN1WPdL4R07s9CC8tshljn@7IuPFNMX0303SH79Kw7bEXnscx9rL01p@vlsrfTzsGBiwtUgnJwtXHg4WKSduU3j4/b950Ybmw2AmWBqcU1Gk7GqgOW5YAIlHXE@TG6KGl6rfA12@R0s15HAYinGWu8oYvQBLobfCzJDN2NERcm8WUX24Wn8XjWBp@mN/RKg7bZC8HfX@p8McApqNriAKcydxVdqPiMRY4q2tOJ2gQZpI5BfxQ8HSH6ZR6eLTIEvtJ5p3mKfHjWD/tgBEVjgXHGULQ5sjuiA6x3mxYpTilUh3Zj48Zhh0FnQz/@5fMVp2Lfsz6Y07cpeBBSKKF9FlhWR3EO1@SxHCuhOY7Ocn@nN0G/YiEnuBmrUunbkPaj@w4Eur6ZnebXa/tRIu0VnQ4biyY7TuF2NLZkKHBHNHSh17tGnbfblmzJLw)</kbd>.